# MSSQL 2008 get all levels of item

Tags: t-sql, xquery-sql

say I have xml in a SQL xml type field e.g.

```
    @x='<root>
         <item>
           <title></title>
           <item>
             <title></title>
           </item>
         </item>
       </root>'
```

How would I go about getting nth level items in a query?

Obviously to get the first level you would use;

```
    select
     t.p.query('.')
    from
     @x.nodes('/root/item') t(p)
```

and to get the next level as well you would add

```
    cross apply
         @x.nodes('/root/item/item')
```

but at runtime we do not know the depth the xml may go to.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all item nodes you can do like this

```
select t.p.query('.')
from @x.nodes('//item') t(p)
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
<item><title /><item><title /></item></item>
<item><title /></item>
```

If you want only the innermost item node you can do like this

```
select
  t.p.query('.')
from @x.nodes('//item[count(item) = 0]') t(p)
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
<item><title /></item>
```

Comment: wow really that simple, just an extra forward slash! thanks very much!